# Java API to convert Array to CSV

Tags: java, csv, utilities

Suppose I have an array of int, float, string etc. Is there any utility API (e.g. Commons, Guava) that will give me a comma separated string?

Like so,

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5}. 
String s = magicAPI.getCSV(a); // s == "1,2,3,4,5";
```

Comment: Arrays.toString(a).substring(1).replaceAll("]$", "") // :P

Comment: @rascio `Arrays#toString` also inserts spaces after each comma, which you can't remove easily with a regex as it might be part of a String (in the case of a `String[]`).

Comment: @assylias Although in that case you probably need to handle the case of the delimiter being part of the string more generally. (By using a full CSV library for instance.

Comment: it was a joke it's the most stupid way I found to do it...it's plenty of better way to do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in the past.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
String[] b = new String[a.length];
for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(stringWriter, ",");
csvWriter.writeNext(b);
```

However, for such a trivial example you might want to just use the a `StringBuilder` and a `for` loop

Comment: Doesn't the writeNext() method NOT require you to insert commas yourself ? Otherwise what's the point ?

Comment: Is there a vectorized version of this?

Answer (score 33):

For this simple use case, you can simply join the strings with comma. If you use Java 8:

```
String csv = String.join(",", yourArray);
```

otherwise [*commons-lang*](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a [`join()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object[],%20char%29) method:

```
String csv = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(yourArray, ",");
```

Comment: getting 

The method join(CharSequence, CharSequence...) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int[])

what do I miss?

Answer (score 6):

You mention [*Google Guava*](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which has the [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) utility for this:

```
String s = Joiner.on(",").join(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

After digging more, I found http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html StringUtils  API in Spring that can do it. Since , I'm already using Spring, I guess I will stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Commons Apache CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/) appears to consolidate 3 other CSV libraries, although I can't find a release post-2007.

A quick look suggests [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want via a `CSVWriter`.

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
 // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
 String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new  method to do thisinstead of going for openCSV

```
public String convertArrayToCsv(String[] IncomingArray)
{
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<IncomingArray.length;i++)
    {
        sb=sb.append(IncomingArray[i]);
        if(i != IncomingArray.length-1)
        {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}//end of convertArrayToCsv method
```