# How to add multiple tags (array) to a single post using jsp and mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, checkbox

I have a problem 
Tecno are the tags: java,php,javascript
my Recoge_datos.jsp

```
String[] tecno=request.getParameterValues("tecno");
try{

java.sql.Connection miConexion=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto_jsp","root","");
java.sql.Statement miStatement=miConexion.createStatement();

String instruccionSql="INSERT INTO USERS (nombre, apellido, usuario, contra, pais, tecno) VAlUES ('" + nombre + "','" + apellido +"','"+ usuario +"','"+ contra +"','" + pais +"','" + tecno + "')";

miStatement.executeUpdate(instruccionSql);

out.println(" Registrado con exito ");
}catch(Exception e){
out.println("Ha habido un error");
}
```

and my formulario_registro.html

```
<form action="Recoge_datos.jsp" method="post">
<tr>
  <td>Tecnologias: </td>
  <td><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tecno" value="Java" id="tecnologias_0">
    Java</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tecno" value="PHP" id="tecnologias_1">
      Php</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tecno" value="JavaScript" id="tecnologias_2">
  JavaScript</label></td>
</tr>
```

In MySQL I have this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@6ecf7e94<br>
```

But it should be java,javascript,php If they were selected
I use the latest version of java and tomcat 9, all the latest version 02/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intended to insert the array as String. If so, you need to convert the array into proper String. You can use `String.join()` in Java 8,

```
String tecnoStr = String.join(",", tecno);
```

For more options to do this, see:

- [Convert String[] to comma separated string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622974/convert-string-to-comma-separated-string-in-java)
- [Java API to convert Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545991/java-api-to-convert-array-to-csv)

Also, **always** use parameterized statement [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-). Your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

```
String instruccionSql = "INSERT INTO USERS (nombre, apellido, usuario, contra, pais, tecno) VAlUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement ps = miConexion.prepareStatement(instruccionSql);
ps.setString(1, nombre);
ps.setString(2, apellido);
ps.setString(3, usuario);
ps.setString(4, contra);
ps.setString(5, pais);
ps.setString(6, tecnoStr);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Also, remember to close the connection, statement at the end (left here for the sake of brevity).