# Is there any function to write 2D Array which fetch the data into csv file?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[][] table = {
                { "fileName", "cadName", "number", "folder_Id", "wC_State",
                        "legacy_Path", "reverified", "createdBy", "iteration",
                        "shouldImport" },
                { "abc.sldprt", "abc.sldprt", "abc.sldprt", "098123",
                        "Working", "C:\\WC", " Empty", "12132019", "2", "True" },
                { "pqr.sldprt", "pqr.sldprt", "pqr.sldprt", "098124", "WIP",
                        "C:\\WC", " Empty", "12092019", "8", "True" },
                { "jku.sldprt", "jku.sldprt", "jku.sldprt", "094123",
                        "Released", "C:\\WC", " Empty", "12072019", "13",
                        "True" },
                { "cmx.sldprt", "cmx.sldprt", "cmx.sldprt", "0981290",
                        "Development", "C:\\WC", "Yes", "12132018", "19",
                        "True" },
                { "abc.sldprt", "abc.sldprt", "abc.sldprt", "09812354",
                        "Working", "C:\\WC", " Empty", "12132019", "3", "True" } };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java API to convert Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545991/java-api-to-convert-array-to-csv)

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch into"? Do you want to read from or write to a CSV file?

Comment: I want to write/Store the 2D array elements into CSV file.

Comment: And how should this CSV look like for this array?

Comment: fileName,cadName,number,folder_Id,wC_State,legacy_Path,reverified,createdBy,iteration,shouldImport
abc.sldprt,abc.sldprt,abc.sldprt,098123,Working,C:\\WC, Empty,12132019,2,True
pqr.sldprt,pqr.sldprt,pqr.sldprt,098124,WIP,C:\\WC, Empty,12092019,8,True
jku.sldprt,jku.sldprt,jku.sldprt,094123,C,C:\\WC, Empty,12072019,13,True
cmx.sldprt,cmx.sldprt,cmx.sldprt,0981290,Development,C:\\WC,Yes,12132018,19,True
abc.sldprt,abc.sldprt,abc.sldprt,09812354,Working,C:\\WC, Empty,12132019,3,True

Comment: Check the duplicate question for answer. If the solutions don't work put your commented code in question itself, with correct formatting, update with the newly gained info too which will prevent down-voting. Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please modify question accordingly to [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without posting your code you risk removal of your question.  Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSVWriter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/AbstractCSVWriter.html) for this with [writeAll()](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/AbstractCSVWriter.html#writeAll(java.util.List)) method. It doesn't work on two dimensional array, but it works with Iterable<String[]> or List<String[]>, so you will need to do conversion first.

```
String[][] table = ...;
List<String[]> convertedTable = Arrays.asList(table);
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFilename));
writer.writeAll(convertedTable);
writer.close();
```

Comment: Michal Horvath thanks that works,exactly i got what i was looking for !!!!

Comment: glad that I was able to help

Answer (score -1):

No, you a way to do this would be to use `Arrays#toString`(Or a custom toString function), while iterating over the outer array